# Sorting Grid Column in magento2?

Tags: magento2.2, grid, php-7

I have created a ui component grid .

How to sorting the admin grid

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">xx_stockmovements_stock_movements.xx_stockmovements_stock_movements_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">xx_stockmovements_stock_movements.xx_stockmovements_stock_movements_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">xx_stockmovements_stock_columns</item>        
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="xx_stockmovements_stock_movements_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">XxStockMovementsGridDataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">xx_stockmovements_stock_movements_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">                    
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>               
    <container name="listing_top">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/toolbar</item>
                <item name="stickyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/sticky/toolbar</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <bookmark name="bookmarks">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">xx_stockmovements_stock_movements</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </bookmark>
        <component name="columns_controls">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="columnsData" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">xx_stockmovements_stock_movements.xx_stockmovements_stock_movements.xx_stockmovements_stock_columns</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/controls/columns</item>
                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">dataGridActions</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </component>
        <exportButton name="export_button">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">xx_stockmovements_stock_movements.xx_stockmovements_stock_movements.xx_stockmovements_stock_movements.ids</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </exportButton>        
        <filters name="listing_filters">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="columnsProvider" xsi:type="string">xx_stockmovements_stock_movements.xx_stockmovements_stock_movements.xx_stockmovements_stock_columns</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">xx_stockmovements_stock_movements.xx_stockmovements_stock_movements.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.filters</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="templates" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="filters" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="select" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select</item>
                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">xx_stockmovements_stock_movements.xx_stockmovements_stock_movements.listing_top.listing_filters</item>
                        <item name="imports" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="visible" xsi:type="string">xx_stockmovements_stock_movements.xx_stockmovements_stock_movements.xx_stockmovements_stock_columns.${ $.index }:visible</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="observers" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="column" xsi:type="string">column</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </filters>       
        <paging name="listing_paging">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">xx_stockmovements_stock_movements.xx_stockmovements_stock_movements.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.paging</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">xx_stockmovements_stock_movements.xx_stockmovements_stock_movements.xx_stockmovements_stock_columns.ids</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </paging>
    </container>
    <columns name="xx_stockmovements_stock_columns">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">xx_stockmovements_stock_movements.xx_stockmovements_stock_movements.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current</item>
                </item>               
                <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">xx_stockmovements_stock_movements.xx_stockmovements_stock_movements.xx_stockmovements_stock_columns_editor</item>
                        <item name="target" xsi:type="string">startEdit</item>
                        <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="0" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                            <item name="1" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">xx_stockmovements_stock_movements.xx_stockmovements_stock_movements.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="root" xsi:type="string">columns.${ $.index }</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.${ $.storageConfig.root}</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
         <column name="product_sku" class="Xx\StockMovements\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Product">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>                   
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Sku</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">desc</item>
                    <!--<item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>-->
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>       
        <column name="qty">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>                   
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Qty</item>
                    <item name="sortable" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="movement">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>                    
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Movement</item>
                    <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>  
        <column name="is_in_stock">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Xx\StockMovements\Model\Column\InStock</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">In Stock</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item> 
                    <item name="sortable" xsi:type="string">asc</item>          
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>        
        <column name="message">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>                   
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Message</item>
                    <item name="sortable" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <filter>textRange</filter>
                <label translate="true">Message</label>
                <sorting>asc</sorting>
            </settings>
        </column>

        <column name="user">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>                    
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">User</item>
                    <item name="sortable" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="created_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Created At</item>
                    <item name="sortable" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>   
    </columns>
</listing>
```

I also trying

```
<item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">desc</item>
<item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
```

But its not working

Comment: Can you please upload your xml code of ui grid?

Comment: @Mano M did you try my solution. if so, please accept the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem.

You first have to do your columns like this:

```
<column name="product_sku" class="Xx\StockMovements\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Product">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>                   
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Sku</item>
            <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">desc</item>
            <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">1</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

Thereafter you need to go to your database table. search for table:

> ui_bookmark

Search for the row that relates to your grid i.e:

```
product_attributes_listing
```

Delete the row and then:

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: Good reference, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Try Below code

```
<column name="product_sku" class="Xx\StockMovements\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Product">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>                   
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Sku</item>
            <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">desc</item>
            <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">1</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

**Remove Cache**

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

**Hope it Helps.**

Answer (score -1):

Have You tried Like below code in Ui_component form file

```
<item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
```